# I'm having a problem with the reduce function in DataTables and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, sum

I'm using the *append* to insert the result of the SQL query in the table when the ajax function returns success, but the console returns **Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value**

**ajax.js**

```
success: function(result)
        {
            var result = JSON.parse(result); 
            $("#tabela").append("<tr>"+result+'</tr>');
            var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
            console.log( 'Column 2 sum: '+
                table
                    .column( 2 )
                    .data()
                    .reduce( function (a,b) {
                        return a + b; })
                        )}
        }
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
        paging: false,
        searching:  false,
        sort:  false,
        language: false ,
        ajax: {
            "url": "consulta.php",
            "data": {
                'cliente' : $("#cliente").val(),
                'filial' : $("#filial").val(),
                'produto' : $("#produto").val(),
                'quantidade' : $("#quantidade").val(),
                'valor' : $("#valor").val()
            }
        }   
    })
            setInterval( function () {
                table.ajax.reload();
            }, 1000 );
});
```

**query.php**

```
 while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $return.= "<td>" . utf8_encode($linha["Item"] . " - " . $linha["Produto"]) . "</td>";
        $return.= "<td class='margem'>" . utf8_encode($linha["Conversao"]) * $valor * $quantidade  . "</td>";
    }
    echo json_encode($return);
```

I've tried a LOT of different approaches already.
What I need is a simple solution to sum the second column every time the button is clicked and the ajax returns the result.

Comment: What do you obtain when you print column 2, using `console.log(table.column(2).data())` ? `reduce` function doesn't work because the content seems to be empty.

Comment: It doesn't return a result, just a lot of empty arrays and definitions from the DataTable itself